# How to Adjust read values from port in a multitask windows form application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I want to read information from one of the system ports and use these data to update (at real time) the values of Windows form's controls (such as textbox, lable, etc), at the same time I want to insert these values corresponding to each control into database (ms sql server).

To update the values of each control, I've written a code like the following code using TPL for each control. The question I have is how to adjust (or sync) the values corresponding to each of the controls at a given time.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    tag = true;
    while (tag)
    {
        string value = readDataFromPort();
        databaseObj.lable1 = value;
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
             label1.Text = value;
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        task.Wait();
    }
});
```

I mean, for example, values for lable1 and lable2 in a database's record are both related to the time T1, and the next values are related to T2 time, and continue until disconnecting (Tag value equal to false). Also, if you know, suggest a better way to use other technologies like threads. I use .NET framework 4.5 on visual studio 2013.

Comment: **values for lable1 and lable2 in a database's record are both related to the time T1** - I can't see a time mentioned over here. As far as I understand this post, you want to update all the controls in the UI and subsequently update their database values when a packet is received. Is that so?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please, rephrase your question.

Comment: @o_O, I want to update all the controls in the UI and subsequently "Set new values" (not update) their database values (in a new record with The corresponding Timestamp) when a packet is received.

Comment: I haven't used Task class much, but I've been using Threads very often. Will a Thread based answer suffice? Also is there some kind of identifier from the data received which would tell, which control should be updated with the particular received string

Comment: @o_O, I use Task class because it's easier but what I want to do is also possible with thread. You can use controlX.updateValue = readData.controlX() To access read data corresponding to each control.

Comment: Can u clarify about how would you differentiate, which packet data belongs to which control

Comment: @o_O,  Each packet has an identifier that can be used to determine which control is associated to it (which specified at above comment by method readData.controlX() ... ) If you know another way, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I told you in the comments one way to implement this is by using Threads,

But first make a `static` extension like:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static void InvokeBy(this Control ctl, MethodInvoker method)
   {
      if (ctl.InvokeRequired)
          ctl.Invoke(method);
      else method();
   }
}
```

Use this `static` class in your main class where you would receive packets and update control. This `static` class is used, so as to avoid *Cross-thread exception* while accessing a control and updating its contents from a child thread to the Main UI thread.

Now the actual work:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
     this.InvokeBy(() =>
     {
           tag = true;
           while (tag)
           {
               string value = readDataFromPort();
               //I'm still not sure about the above method, what would be the value of 
               //control IDENTIFIER you might get 
               //along with the packet. As you said in the comments using:
               //"controlX.updateValue = readData.controlX()",
               //you can differentiate controls with their respective packets.
               //So let'say you get the Control's NAME as IDENTIFIER, then:
               string controlName = "Control Name goes here";

               var controls = this.Controls;
               //you can use Controls.OfType<Label>() to spefically 
               //pick a certain type of control from the UI

               foreach (Control control in controls)
               {
                   if (control.Name == controlName)
                   {
                        control.InvokeBy(() =>
                        {
                             //replace this with database object of the control
                             databaseObj.lable1 = value;

                             //If you've got some other differentiation to be
                             //used among the controls, implement if-else conditions
                             //and then update their respective value
                             control.Text = value;
                        });
                   }
               }
           }
       });
   });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Hope you get some idea on how to get started with this!

Comment: I did not know about extension methods! I'll try it... .

Comment: Keep the static class under the same namespace as in your main class, so as to easily access its extension method

Comment: Would you please explain about "thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);"

Comment: STA means single threaded application.. It is used to manage access level of the threads u create in your application. You can also set MTA ie multi threaded application but then your control access would cause some troubles. You may read more about it at [apartment state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As I said, I use dedicated tasks to update value of each control and I was looking for a method to adjust the timestamps (time that's when that value of each control is updated ) for values of all controls, but in your method, only one thread is used to update values of all controls and all values corresponding to each control have same timestamp. Which method is better?

Comment: As I told you earlier that I haven't worked with Task library, thus I can't give you a black and white answer which one works better. But if this answer worked for you, take bits and pieces from it and integrate it into your solution and check how does it hold up. Also if I use for example `obj.Value = Datetime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")` inside the `foreach` loop I believe you would get different timestamps to the last of the millisecond every time the iteration happens. So do some extensive testing to know which would fit your scenario better :)